# Selenium - Click on a button until some element appears

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js

I am trying to click on the `Check for new emails` button of the [Yopmail's website](http://yopmail.com) until an email is received (because at the beginning the inbox is empty).

I am using the `NodeJS` implementation of `Selenium`, running my tests with `Mocha`. Here is how I am trying to click until the element appears :

```
driver.get('http://yopmail.com');
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.css('#f .sbut')));
driver.findElement(By.name('login')).sendKeys(name);
driver.findElement(By.css('#f .sbut')).sendKeys(Key.ENTER);
driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id('ifinbox')));// Switching iframe
driver.switchTo().frame("ifinbox");


bool = driver.isElementPresent("m1");


while (!bool) {
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  driver.findElement(By.id("lrefr")).click();
  driver.sleep(500);// 500ms
  driver.switchTo().frame("ifinbox");
  bool = driver.isElementPresent("m1");
}
```

The ligne `bool = driver.isElementPresent("m1");` fails with the following unexplicite error message :

```
    Error: the error {} was thrown, throw an Error :)
        at Array.forEach (native)
```

I guess I can't build a while loop on a promise... maybe... But then I dont really understand why it fails, and how to write this while loop properly.

Any suggestion is most welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/09ec0b84cd8fdc4c957018457b02561a66c6390e/javascript/webdriver/webdriver.js#L972), `isElementPresent()` accepts a locator or an element, but you are passing in a string `m1`. Assuming this is an `id`:

```
bool = driver.isElementPresent(By.id("m1"));
```

Comment: You are right. Maybe I can't read [this documentation properly then](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_class_WebDriver.html#isElementPresent). I believe it is written there I can pass a string as an argument, which will be tried against the className, id, etc. No? Thank you very much anyway! I have been struggling with this for a couple of hours already

Comment: @AlexandreBourlier I think the docs are a bit confusing here - they probably just trying to specify what type of locators can be used here..

Comment: I think you are right. This is what confused me. Now I'll know. 
Thanks again